# Can't access the Acumos portal

Tags: acumos

Background： VMware15.0 ubuntu16.04-64bit 32G RAM + 16Core CPU

/etc/hosts: 192.168.79.130 localhost

Doing this (and typing the sudo password when prompted):

```
git clone https://gerrit.acumos.org/r/system-integration
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install docker-ce=18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu
if [[ "$(id -nG "$USER" | grep docker)" == "" ]]; then sudo usermod -aG docker $USER; fi
sudo visudo #add
jp ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
# Logged out and in again and verified that my user is in the docker group
cd system-integration/tools/
sudo bash setup_k8s_stack.sh setup
cd
sudo bash system-integration/AIO/setup_prereqs.sh k8s localhost $USER generic 2>&1 | tee aio_prep.log
# When "Prerequisites setup is complete" messages is displayed I continue with
cd system-integration/AIO
sudo bash oneclick_deploy.sh 2>&1 | tee aio_deploy.log
```

Successful implementation with the following tips：

```
oneclick_deploy.sh main:384 (Tue Sep 24 20:39:44 PDT 2019) Deploy is complete.
You can access the Acumos portal and other services at the URLs below,
assuming hostname "localhost" is resolvable from your workstation:
Portal: https://localhost
Common Data Service Swagger UI: https://localhost/ccds/swagger-ui.html
Portal Swagger UI: https://localhost/api/swagger-ui.html
Onboarding Service Swagger UI: https://localhost/onboarding-app/swagger-ui.html
Kibana: http://localhost:30561/app/kibana
Nexus: http://localhost:30881
```

When I use chrome to access the Acumos portal("https://localhost"),tips:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

And if access "https://192.168.79.130", tips:

```
default backend - 404
```

Only "http://192.168.79.130:30881/" and "http://192.168.79.130:30561/app/kibana" can be accessed successfully.
But if "192.168.79.130" is replaced by "localhost", the browser's state is "loading".

I'm sure there's something wrong with it. I sincerely hope to be guided again. Thank you.

Comment: Not confident of those instructions but I may be out of date also - the portal web server once listened at port 30080. I've again asked the A.I.O. expert to respond here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glad you were able to get it running. It's curious that localhost will not allow a connection. Is the '/etc/hosts: 192.168.79.130 localhost' info from your host, or the VM? Note that if this is from the VM, it won't work as your browser will try to connect to "localhost" as your host, not the VM. When you use the IP address, then your browser will connect to the VM. So make sure you assign a domain name (e.g. "acumos") to the IP address of your VM, in your host /etc/hosts file. Also, to check why you might be getting the 'default backend - 404' response, inside the VM, make sure that the inginx-ingress controller is running, e.g.

`NAME                                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
acumos-nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.109.8.56     10.1.0.14     80:30080/TCP,443:30443/TCP   8d
acumos-nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.105.216.16   <none>        80/TCP                       8d`

..., that the ingress rule for the Portal is setup:

`kubectl get ingress -n acumos portal-ingress
NAME             HOSTS                            ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
portal-ingress   (per your VM domain)             80, 443   8d`

..., and with ingress details for your VM, that connect you to the running Portal-FE:

`kubectl describe ingress -n acumos portal-ingress
Name:             portal-ingress
Namespace:        acumos
Address:

Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  ingress-cert terminates (your VM domain)
Rules:
  Host                                               Path  Backends
  ----                                               ----  --------
  (your VM domain)                                   /   portal-fe-service:8085 (<none>)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:  nginx
Events:                         <none>`

``

Comment: lo.ol, did Bryan's answer work for you? can you load the portal UI in a browser?

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy lately and haven't tried. Yesterday I upgraded the AIO version to 3.0, and there was a new error：setup_jenkins.sh fail:42     connect to 192.168.79.130 port 443 failed: Connection refused

Comment: Bryan, chrisinmtown, I am gratitude to you for helping me. After I used AIO 3.0.1, the installation was successful. Now the Acumos platform can be accessed and run normally.